# how to upload images for my project in libgdx

Tags: java, file-upload, libgdx

how can I insert a drag and drop part for uploading images in my project.
I need this part so that users can upload their image for their profile in game.

I read so many pages in Google but I found nothing.
There is only the way to import your project on Libgdx.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the test code here

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-lwjgl3/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/lwjgl3/DragNDropTest.java#L77

Key bit is this

```
config.setWindowListener(new Lwjgl3WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void filesDropped (String[] files) {
                for (String file : files) {
                    Gdx.app.log("GLWF Drop", file);
                }
                test.addFiles(files);
            }

        });
```